# How to create a custom client RESTLET Request and/or Response Entity Java object with notations?

Tags: rest, restlet

Is there a good tutorial (or question and answer here) to illustrate how to create a custom RESTLET Request and/or Response Entity Java object with notations?

I have a RESTLET server application that has well defined methods (i.e. GET, PUT, POST, etc.) with responses.  I'd like to write a Java client code piece that connects to it and uses JSON annotations, if possible, to parse out the RESTLET requests and responses of the RESTLET client.  Everything I've found so far online is about writing the RESTLET service, not about the client.

I've been able to use "org.restlet.resource.ClientResource" as the connector client to connect to URL and parse out a response. but I'd like a more generic way to do this with a Java POJO object that uses @notations (i.e. @GET @POST) defined methods and object to send and receive the client's request's and responses.

I have something similar to this right now:

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(url);

Request request = new Request(Method.POST, url);

clientResource.setRequest(request);
Form form = new Form();

form.set("foo", "barValue");

org.restlet.representation.Representation   response = clientResource.post(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Representation responseEntity = clientResource.getResponseEntity();

JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation = new JsonRepresentation(responseEntity);

JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject();
String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);

if (jsonObject.has("errorString"))
{
    String error = jsonObject.optString("errorString");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that that you look for is the  converter concept. The latter are supported on both client and server sides and aims to convert representations to POJOs. You can notice that you need to use ClientResource to leverage such feature.

You can have a look at the Jackson one within the extension org.restlet.extract.jackson. This will help you to implement your own one.

Hope it will help!

Comment: So, is Jackson a framework / .jar that needs to be installed and used separately?  Is there anything native to the RESTLET framework that does this?

Comment: Yes, Jackson needs to be in your classpath. In fact, Restlet provides the generic frame for representation data conversion but generally delegates the actual conversion to a third-part tool. In fact I'm not sure to correctly understand your question. Do you want to use Restlet annotations on the client side? If so, you must use annotated interfaces with the method wrap of the class ClientResource. If it's what you need, I'll post a new and detailled answer to your question...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use annotated interfaces in Restlet, you simply need to define interfaces as described below:

```
public TestResource {
  @Get
  List<Element> getElements();
  @Post
  Element addElement(Element element);
}
```

This corresponds to a server resource that has HTTP methods GET and POST and handle a data structure same as the structure of the class Element (no matter the technology used: JSON, XML, YAML and so on).

For example:

```
public class Element {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private int age;
  // Setters and getters
 (...)
}
```

Corresponding content:

```
{
  "id": "myid",
  "name": "myname",
  "age": 35
}
```

This interface can be used within the class ClientResource with the method wrap, as described below:

```
 ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://(...)/myresource");
 ElementResource resource = cr.wrap(ElementResource.class);
 // GET
 List<Element> elements = resource.getElements();
 // POST
 Element newElement = new Element();
 newElement.setId("...");
 (...)
 Element addedElement = resource.addElement(newElement);
```

You can notice that the representation data / POJO is done under the hood by Restlet. So you need to have an extension that does this. For example the extension org.resdtlet.ext.jackson to use Jackson for JSON or XML or YAML.

Hope it helps.
Thierry